# Handsontable row click error

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I'm using handsontable and try to contextMenu to work. But I'm always having an error when I click a new row created and also the above row doesn't work

here is my configuration:

```
var $laborTable = $("#exampleGrid");
$laborTable.handsontable({
    stretchH: 'all',
    startCols: 7,
    rowHeaders: true,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    columnSorting: true,
    contextMenu: ['remove_row', 'row_above', 'row_below'],
    colWidths: function (index) {
        if (index == 7) {
            return 5;
        }
    },
    colHeaders: ["Labor Code", "Description", "Person", "Hour", "Rate", "Amount", "Benefits"],
    columns: [{
        type: 'autocomplete',
        source: ["BMW", "Chrysler", "Nissan", "Suzuki", "Toyota", "Volvo"],
        strict: false
    }, {
        type: 'autocomplete',
        source: ["yellow", "red", "orange", "green", "blue", "gray", "black", "white"],
        strict: true,
        allowInvalid: false
    }, {
        type: 'numeric'
    }, {
        type: 'numeric'
    }, {
        type: 'numeric'
    }, {
        type: 'numeric'
    }, {
        type: "checkbox"
    }],
    myPlugin: false
});
```

here is my sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hU6Kz/2724/)

Thank you in advance

Comment: what error do you get? Your fiddle works fine here. I can select the values, change them, a new row gets added, ...

Comment: @VDesign Insert a row below and try to edit that row or Insert row above. Nothing shows up.

Comment: Works fine here. I can insert a row above or below, edit the rows, ...

Comment: That's odd. What browser are you using? Did you edit the same row that is inserted?

Comment: Mozilla firefox 29.0.1. I will try other browsers

Comment: Ok in Chrome it doesn't work! Also not in ie10.

Comment: Try Chrome Version 34.0.1847.137